# Limit combinations to a particular size

Tags: java, combinations

I am trying to generate key and value combinations of elements stored in a Map>

eg: {3=[16], 2=[11, 12], 1=[5, 7], 0=[1, 3]}

Need to get combinations as

```
                [0,1]-> [[1,5],[1,7],[3,5],[3,7]]
                [0,2]-> [[1,11],[1,12],[3,11],[3,12]] and so on..
```

Currently I am able to get these combinations.

But I am facing an issue
1. I need to get only the combination for map.size -1 
 ie currently my results are

```
FINAL RESULT*** [3]===[ 16]
FINAL RESULT*** [2]===[ 11,  12]
FINAL RESULT*** [1]===[ 5,  7]
FINAL RESULT*** [0]===[ 1,  3]
FINAL RESULT*** [3, 2]===[ 16 11,  16 12]
FINAL RESULT*** [3, 1]===[ 16 5,  16 7]
FINAL RESULT*** [3, 0]===[ 16 1,  16 3]
FINAL RESULT*** [2, 1]===[ 11 5,  11 7,  12 5,  12 7]
FINAL RESULT*** [2, 0]===[ 11 1,  11 3,  12 1,  12 3]
FINAL RESULT*** [1, 0]===[ 5 1,  5 3,  7 1,  7 3]
FINAL RESULT*** [3, 2, 1]===[ 16 11 5,  16 11 7,  16 12 5,  16 12 7]
FINAL RESULT*** [3, 2, 0]===[ 16 11 1,  16 11 3,  16 12 1,  16 12 3]
FINAL RESULT*** [3, 1, 0]===[ 16 5 1,  16 5 3,  16 7 1,  16 7 3]
FINAL RESULT*** [2, 1, 0]===[ 11 5 1,  11 5 3,  11 7 1,  11 7 3,  12 5 1,  12 5 3,  12 7 1,  12 7 3]
FINAL RESULT*** [3, 2, 1, 0]===[ 16 11 5 1,  16 11 5 3,  16 11 7 1,  16 11 7 3,  16 12 5 1,  16 12 5 3,  16 12 7 1,  16 12 7 3]
```

I need only

```
FINAL RESULT*** [3, 2, 1]===[ 16 11 5,  16 11 7,  16 12 5,  16 12 7]
FINAL RESULT*** [3, 2, 0]===[ 16 11 1,  16 11 3,  16 12 1,  16 12 3]
FINAL RESULT*** [3, 1, 0]===[ 16 5 1,  16 5 3,  16 7 1,  16 7 3]
FINAL RESULT*** [2, 1, 0]===[ 11 5 1,  11 5 3,  11 7 1,  11 7 3,  12 5 1,  12 5 3,  12 7 1,  12 7 3]
```

My current code is [here](https://paste.ee/p/9oizB)

Where should I keep this condition?

Answer (score 0):

In your

```
private static void GenCombinations(String[] head, String[] tail, int headIndex, int tailIndex)
```

method you could do a check on the length of the head array and return if it's not three.

so add

```
   if (head.length != 3) {
       return;
   }
```

at the top of that method and it should print what you want. You can replace 3 with what ever condition you want, such as the size of the map - 1 or what ever you needed.